# как вывести фото

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

начал изучать php и есть вопрос, у меня такая задача интересная для меня , я делаю сайт фотографу. 
Сверстал я страницу галлереи у каждого дива с фото свой класс , сделал пока в тестовом 5 фото.
как в разные дивы выводить по очередности фото?

Comment: Вы понимаете, что в браузере отображается HTML-разметка, а PHP всего лишь генерирует эту разметку?

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать например так (костыли, но работать будет)

```
$photos = array(0 => '/img/1.jpg', 1 => '/img/2.jpg', 2 => '/img/3.jpg', 3 => '/img/4.jpg', 4 => '/img/5.jpg', 5 => '/img/6.jpg'); // массив фотографий

$classes = array(0 => 'div1', 1 => 'div2', 2 => 'div3', 3 => 'div4', 4 => 'div5');  // массив классов

$counter = 0;
foreach($photos as $key=>$value) {
echo "<div class='$classes[$counter]'><img src='$value' /></div>";
$counter++;
$counter = ($counter>=count($classes)-1)?0:$counter;
}
```

А вообще как по мне, лучше стандартизировать стили, чтобы весь контент выводился по одному шаблону без каких либо спецефических изменений классов и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь !